# Issue with inner join when running query

Tags: database, postgresql

I am attempting to run the following query in postgres:

```
update changeitem c inner join issuestatus s on s.id = c.oldvalue and c.field = 'status' set oldstring = s.pname;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "inner"
LINE 1: update changeitem c inner join issuestatus s on s.id = c.old...
```

I am not completely sure what is wrong with my statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
update changeitem c 
set oldstring = s.pname
from issuestatus s 
where s.id = c.oldvalue 
and c.field = 'status';
```

Comment: Perfecto! That worked. Can you explain why this works and mine didnt?

Comment: Sure! That's how the postres syntax is. It allows us to "join" a second table using `from` clause, just like I did. if you need to "join" a 3rd table, then you can use `join` clause. `update changeitem c 
set oldstring = s.pname
from issuestatus s 
join anothertable at on at.somecolumn = s.somecolumn 
where s.id = c.oldvalue 
and c.field = 'status';`

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I appreciate the help. I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately UPDATE does not support explicit joins using the JOIN keyword. Check [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) please.

Answer (score 0):

Correct query:

```sql
UPDATE c 
SET oldstring = s.pname
FROM changeitem c 
WHERE c.field = 'status' 
AND c.id in (SELECT s.id FROM issuestatus s WHERE s.id = c.oldvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :
Not Tested :

```
update changeitem as c set oldstring = s.pname from issuestatus as s where s.id = c.oldvalue and c.field = 'status' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be performed with an `UPDATE WITH` clause:

```
update changeitem c 
set oldstring = s.pname
from issuestatus s
where  s.id = c.oldvalue and c.field = 'status';
```

see [this sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/caa9d/1/0)